# Jquery validate plugin -submitHandler set as default to work across multiple forms?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I was trying to build this validation module using JQuery Validate Plugin, working across multiple forms. So, I decided to put the common functions/rules in the jQuery.validator.setDefaults() method that the plugin provides. So, only the success function of the plugin needs to be in different places.

```
$("#myForm").validate(
   success: function(label){
      window.location = someURL;
   }
);
```

SubmitHandler was one of them (in the setDefaults method), and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting the default page on clicking submit, if the form is invalid. Is there a return false or preventDefault() kind of a thing for submitHandler()?

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function(form){
    var url = $(form).attr('action') ;
    var data = $(form).serialize()+'&ajax_validation=1';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        //something
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Can anybody help? Somebody who has tried to deal with multiple forms using jQuery validate plugin? Help will be appreciated. Let me know if elaboration needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `return false` at the end of the `submitHandler` callback to prevent the default form action.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var url = $(form).attr('action') ;
        var data = $(form).serialize()+'&ajax_validation=1';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                //something
            }
        });
        return false;  // <-- add this line
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  [http://jsfiddle.net/SySGN/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/SySGN/)

*Edited jsFiddle with OP's inline class rules.  Still working the same.*

---

**EDIT 2:**

I just noticed the content of your success function.

```
$("#myForm").validate(
   success: function(label){
      window.location = someURL;  // <-- WHY?!
   }
);
```

*What* are you trying to do with that?   *When* exactly do you think `success` fires?  ***Why* would you try to load a new URL in the middle of validating the form?**

**Quote OP:**

> *"I'm getting the default page on clicking submit, if the form is invalid"*

That's because as soon as you fill in the first field, `success` fires and redirects the page to `someURL`.  How do you expect the user to finish filling in the form if you change to a new page before he's done?

`success` is simply a callback function that fires to show the label whenever an element *passes* validation.  It was designed for things like placing icons next to successfully filled in fields and such.

[The `success` callback function, as per jQuery Validate docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a **valid** element.  If a String is given, it is added as a `class` to the `label`. If a Function is given, it is called with the `label` (as a jQuery object) and the validated input (as a DOM element). The `label` can be used to add a text like “ok!”.

You're already submitting the form with `.ajax()`, so reloading the page at any point in the process defeats the whole purpose of `.ajax()`.  I cannot even suggest alternative code since I can't imagine what you're trying to do.  All I can say is that you'd *only* use the `submitHandler` callback to fire code upon submit after the whole form passes validation.

Is it possible you got jQuery Validate `success` confused with `.ajax()` `success`?  The latter is already *inside* the `.ajax()` which is inside your `submitHandler`.  However, again, `.ajax()` allows you to submit data without reloading the page, so a redirect to another page makes the `.ajax()` totally pointless.

Comment: Hi Sparky, thanks for the answer. However, I figured the problem is this: the validate plugin validates only the first invalid element, after that, it submits the form. I even have name attributes in all my input fields. Been on this since 2 days now. Can you help?

Comment: Also, I'm using no rules, only class="required" in input fields, since thats all I want for now.

Comment: **Quote @Meet**: _"I'm using no rules, only `class="required"` in input fields"_ ~ Those are your rules but it makes no difference... still working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/SySGN/1/

Comment: @Meet, what are you trying to do here with this code:  `window.location = someURL`?  See my edited answer.  Redirecting to a new URL in this context is not making sense.

Comment: Hi, yeah I was totally getting the success function wrong. I had this onSuccess function in a custom validator that a previous guy had written, and I had to replace using jquery validate plugin, so got me confused. Thanks for the trouble. It works totally fine now. :)